# How to add multiple pagers in same page, with db_select queries? (In AJAX)

Tags: database, paging

How to apply a pager with [db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x)?

I have setup a query like that:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_data_field_author_text', 'au', 'n.nid = au.entity_id');
$query->join('field_data_field_date', 'da', 'n.nid = da.entity_id');
$query->fields('n',array('title','created','type','nid'));
$query->fields('au',array('field_author_text_value'));
$query->fields('da',array('field_date_value'));
$query->condition('n.type', 'conference', '=');
$query->condition('n.language', $language->language, '=');
$or = db_or(); //Mandatory for OR conditions
$or->condition('au.field_author_text_value', '%' .db_like($keywords). '%', 'LIKE');
$or->condition('n.title', '%' .db_like($keywords). '%', 'LIKE');
$query->condition($or);
$query->orderBy('da.field_date_value', 'DESC');
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Then, I can print my results this way:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value){

  print '<li>';
  $title = $value->title;
  $author_text_title = $value->field_author_text_value;
  $node_alias = url(drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$value->nid));

  $field_title_excerpt = (search_excerpt($keywords, ' '.$title.' '));
  print '<div class="krown-search-results-title"><a href="'.$node_alias.'">'.$field_title_excerpt.'</a></div>';

  $author_text_title_excerpt = (search_excerpt($keywords, ' '.$author_text_title.' '));
  print '<div class="krown-search-results-texte">'.$author_text_title_excerpt.'</div>';

  print '</li>';

}
```

Here is what my output looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I tried to apply a pager this way:

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);
```

Unfortunately, this is not working? Anyone has an idea how to achieve that? The best would be a page with AJAX feature!

**EDIT**

After I updated my code according to @Clive comment, the pager work perfectly as expected,many thanks!

Here is my code now:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_data_field_author_text', 'au', 'n.nid = au.entity_id');
$query->join('field_data_field_date', 'da', 'n.nid = da.entity_id');
$query->fields('n',array('title','created','type','nid'));
$query->fields('au',array('field_author_text_value'));
$query->fields('da',array('field_date_value'));
$query->condition('n.type', 'conference', '=');
$query->condition('n.language', $language->language, '=');
$or = db_or(); //Mandatory for OR conditions
$or->condition('au.field_author_text_value', '%' .db_like($keywords). '%', 'LIKE');
$or->condition('n.title', '%' .db_like($keywords). '%', 'LIKE');
$query->condition($or);
$query->orderBy('da.field_date_value', 'DESC');
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(5);
$result = $query->execute();

print '<h3>Publications</h3>';
print '<ul id="results-list">';

foreach ($result as $key => $value){

  print '<li>';
  $title = $value->title;
  $author_text_title = $value->field_author_text_value;
  $node_alias = url(drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$value->nid));

  $field_title_excerpt = (search_excerpt($keywords, ' '.$title.' '));
  print '<div class="krown-search-results-title"><a href="'.$node_alias.'">'.$field_title_excerpt.'</a></div>';

  $author_text_title_excerpt = (search_excerpt($keywords, ' '.$author_text_title.' '));
  print '<div class="krown-search-results-texte">'.$author_text_title_excerpt.'</div>';

  print '</li>';

}

print '</ul>';
print theme('pager');
```

And here is what my page looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to display several pagers independent of each other?

And also, how can I turn them into AJAX featured?

Comment: It won't create pager with adding `limit()` in your query. Did you try views module for creating the list?

Comment: I tried without limit(), but it doesn't work. Of course I know views module, but I must do something very specific, and I would like to avoid as much as possible contrib modules. I prefer go with custom for this module.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? You've asked for 10 results, you've got 10 results, so seems like it's working to me...is it the lack of pager links that's concerning you? If so it's because you haven't printed them (`print theme('pager');`)

Comment: Thank you @Clive, it worked perfectly as expected!! Now is there an easy way to turn the Pager in AJAX!? I have several lists in same page, I need to have independent pagers for each of them.